# Breakdown Windows Network IO by network adapter and by process

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, performance-monitoring

What I'm trying to do is breakdown the Network IO by network adapter and by Process. The goal is to identify which processes are generating the most IO on a certain network adapter.

Resource Monitor allows to monitor Network IO by process, or Network IO by adapter, but not break it down by the 2 parameters (process + network), so you can see the IO on a certain adapter but you can't discern which of all the running processes are exactly contributing to that IO.

Or you can see how much Network IO is generating each process, but you can't discern over which network adapter.

The same limitation with Windows Perf Counters, Process Monitor, Process Explorer, etc.

Do you have some suggestions, from your experience, as to which utility would be good for this task ? I'm not looking for an advanced capturing tool, just need to count the Network IO by process over a certain adapter.

Look forward to hearing from you :)